# Flutter Azure Devops publish bundle on Google Play

Tags: flutter, azure-devops, google-play

I have a Flutter application that I build with Azure Devops. I generated a bundle of . aab format
I use the Google Play Release Bundle task to publish my package to the store but get the following error: package not found.
However I have well informed the applicationId which is in my Manifest.xml. It is form com.exemple.myApp

What is the problem ?

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots of the error?

Comment: I have it in the description the error message. I am not more info. He just tells me that he can’t find my package whose name I passed as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code in your azure pipeline ?

```
A task example :

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Execute Dart program'
  inputs:
    script: '$(FlutterToolPath)/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart program.dart arg1 arg2'
    workingDirectory: 'src'
```

Comment: What does this command do? I don’t use yml. I do the pipelines with the graphical interface